# Character array passed in double quotes to a function

Tags: c++, string, memcpy

What happens behind the scene when a string in double quotes is passed as an argument to a function? Where is memory allocated for that string?

If I do `memcpy(ptr, "SINGH", strlen("SINGH")+1);`, output is `SINGH` only. From where is the extra byte copied from?

For below program:

```
void func(char *ptr) {
    memcpy(ptr, "SINGH", strlen("SINGH"));
    cout << ptr << endl; /* Output is SINGHHELLO */
    /* If I do memcpy(ptr, "SINGH", strlen("SINGH")+1); Output is SINGH only. From where does extra byte is copied from? */
}

int main() {
    char str[11] = "HELLOHELLO";
    char str2[10] = "ABC";
    memcpy(str, "HELLO", strlen("HELLO")); /* Where is memory allocated for string 'HELLO' ? */
    cout << str << endl << str2 << endl;
    func(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C or C++ - make up your mind.

Comment: As with any C-style array, it gets converted to a pointer. In this case to a `const char*` pointer to the first character.

Comment: edited my question /* If I do memcpy(ptr, "SINGH", strlen("SINGH")+1); Output is SINGH only. From where does extra byte is copied from? */ When used with memcpy, where does extra byte is copied from?

Comment: `"SINGH"` is an array of 6 chars and the last char is a null

Answer (score -1):

the `"something"` is called the string literal and it is just the sequence of chars (which actually is an array) in the the read only memory.

When you call any function which takes a parameters of type pointer to char the address to this string literal (which in the fact is the array of chars) is passed to this function.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but [the type](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7a9dIBHsbRHH8dJx) of string literal is  `const char[size]`.